Fix color coding when plotting in for loop with seaborn/matplotlib
I am plotting multiple scatter plots in a for loop and the "hue" is set according to a specific dimension. This dimension can either take on the value 1 or 0. Thus I am defining the palette to also have 2 colors only:
colors = ["#6e0303", "#2d659c"]
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))

When I then plot in a for loop the scatter plot, the hue for 1 takes on the one color for some of the plots and the other for the rest of the plots.
However, I want the color to always be fixed_
1 -> "#6e0303"
0 -> "#2d659c"
I am calling the following code inside the foor loop:
plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x_col", y="y_col", hue="my_dimension")

Is there a way to achieve this?

For this, you will only need to slightly tweak the logic you have in place. First, you will need to change your colors variable from an array to a dict:
colors = {0: "#2d659c", 1: "#6e0303"}

Then, you will need to use Seaborn's palette argument with the dictionary:
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x_col", y="y_col", hue="my_dimension", palette=colors)

